# Flatten/Unflatten data from Entities to Models with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, automapper

I would like to flatten/unflatten some classes using automapper, but not sure if this is possible.  I have a ListDefo and ValueDefo, which are how the list and values are defined.  Then a user can add them to a data object. I am not worried about storing the ValueDefo Id against the DataValue, as i just need the string value.  Here are the classes

```
public class ListDefo {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ValueDefo> Values { get; set; }
}

public class ValueDefo {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Data {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DataValue> Values { get; set; }
}

public class DataValue {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ListDefo ListDefo { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Currently if i use automapper, i will have the following models, which i get a Data object with a Values property, and each DataValue with have an Id, ListDefoId and Value.

```
public class DataModel {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DataValueModel> Values { get; set; }
}

public class DataValueModel {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long ListId { get; set; }
    public string Value{ get; set; }
}
```

This is fine i suppose, but i thought it would be cleaner, if instead a data object has a list of lists, then each list just has the values.  So it would look like this

```
public class DataModel {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DataListModel> Lists { get; set; }
}

public class DataListModel {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DataValueModel> Values { get; set; }
}

public class DataValueModel {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Value{ get; set; }
}
```

Is this possible to do using automapper?  I would like to do it back again as well

I could do this easily if i changed my entities to store the data like the models, but it would be pointless to have the list record which just links up the data record and value records

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom mapping/resolvers](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers) to flatten/unflatten classes with Automapper, however the more hierarchy that your classes have the more complex your resolver would be.

You can keep the same hierarchy of your models(DTOs) but remove all properties that you think that the client shouldn't set, now when you want to map-back to the original entity from the DTO, you can ignore these properties and map just the properties that your model (DTO) has.